# Synaptic JS LSTM taking too much memory

Tags: javascript, neural-network, lstm

Using https://github.com/cazala/synaptic package

I've tried LSTM module via Architect with following configuration:

```
var LSTM = new synaptic.Architect.LSTM(100, 100, 20);
```

My algorithm then make about 450 - 500 iterations and at each iteration it activates network and then propagates correct output values.

```
var output = LSTM.activate(HistoricalFrame);
//some code
LSTM.propagate(0.5, PredictionFrame);
```

And after 400 - 500 iterations it suddenly stops and start taking about 14GB of memory. Before this single step it uses about 1GB.

I don't know if it is caused by traces or optimization but the network is then unusable.

I've tested rest of code for memory leaks and I found that problem is caused by activate function.

This is sample code which demonstrates this issue. On my MacBook Pro with Intel Core i5 and 8GB RAM it stops on step 512 and start eating memory up to 14GB.

```
var synaptic = require("synaptic");

//Define frames
var HistoricalFrame = [];
var PredictionFrame = [];

var HistoricalFrameSize = 100;
var PredictionFrameSize = 20;

var FrameCount = 25000;

//Create LSTM
console.log("Initializing LSTM...");
var LSTM = new synaptic.Architect.LSTM(HistoricalFrameSize, HistoricalFrameSize, PredictionFrameSize);

console.log("Optimizing LSTM...");
LSTM.optimize();

console.log("Starting prediction...");

//Make predictions
for(var FrameIndex = 0; FrameIndex < FrameCount; FrameIndex++){

    console.log(FrameIndex);

    //Add value to frame(s)
    PredictionFrame.push(Math.random());

    //Move first value from prediction frame to historical frame
    if(PredictionFrame.length > PredictionFrameSize){
        HistoricalFrame.push( PredictionFrame.shift() );
    }

    //Throw away first value from historical frame to keep the max size
    if(HistoricalFrame.length > HistoricalFrameSize)
        HistoricalFrame.shift();

    //Activate LSTM when frames are filled
    if(HistoricalFrame.length == HistoricalFrameSize){

        var output = LSTM.activate(HistoricalFrame);
        LSTM.propagate(0.5, PredictionFrame);

    }

}
```

Any ideas where problem can be?

I've also posted this as issue https://github.com/cazala/synaptic/issues/56

I've tried Python PyBrain library which is really fast but it has different implementation of neural networks and LSTM. I need exact implementation by following paper because it has the best results.

http://www.overcomplete.net/papers/nn2012.pdf

Comment: Hmm. Maybe try [Neataptic](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic) as the front-end is similar to synaptic, however the back-end works differently.